# when user click at spot oixel move to that spot and pixel should look in motion in assembly language

Tags: assembly

my object is a pixel is on screen already and when user click at any spot on the screen pixel will move to that position and the movement of pixel should show mean it show like animation i have make this in assembly language but issue is pixel is not showing animation. it only move from one place to click spot but animation is not show
my code is:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.code

main proc
    ;select of vedio mode
    mov ah,0
    mov Al,4
    int 10h

;mouse check
    mov ax,0
    int 33h
;show mouse 
    mov ax,1
    int 33h


    MOUSLOOP:


;get click information
    MOV AX,5        
    INT 33h    
    CMP aX,1        
    JE MOUSLOOP     
 ;writ pixel at click position      
    mov ah,0ch
    mov al,01

inc cx
inc dx
int 10h
mov al,0
int 10h
JMP MOUSLOOP
;screen stay
    mov ah,01
    int 21h
;return to text mode
    mov ah,0
    mov al,3
    int 10h
;exit
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

main endp
end main
```

please help what can i do for animation the code should be in assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new so I don't have the points to leave a comment so I need to leave this as an answer.

I think your code is blocking until you get input from the mouse buttons. Try updating the position in the loop:

```
;get click information
    MOV AX,5        
    INT 33h    
    CMP aX,1        
    JE MOUSLOOP
```

otherwise you're stuck with it waiting on button clicks and doing nothing to update position of the cursor.

Also, what do you mean by animation? Do you want the cursor to follow mouse position, do you want the cursor itself to be an animation, do you want both, or is the animation totally unrelated to the cursor and position of the mouse?

I am assuming you wish the current cursor position to animate a movement from the location it is in to the location of the click. I think you can do this with int 10 and the cursor position coordinates, remove cursor and redraw in the new location.
pseudo-code:

```
while dx is not equal to current click position:
mov ax, 0
int 33h
mov ax, 4
mov dx, column
mov cx, row
int 33h
mov ax, 2
int 33h
```

I think it should look something similar, logically, to this.

Comment: i need to move pixel not cursor